# Question about the definition of norms

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I've been given the following question:

[image]

I'm finding it really confusing though, because I thought one of the conditions in the definition of norms was for the function to be greater than or equal to 0 for any vector. However if all values of aj are negative, then the sum will be negative too. This means the positivity condition isn't met.
So, how is this function still a norm?

Comment: Can you write out the question instead of pasting a screenshot? This way it can be found more easily via search engines / for future reference

Comment: Read the question - WHEN is it a norm.

Comment: Your objection is part of the solution. You need to state some conditions on $a_j$ such that that is a norm. You have already seen that if all are negative it does not work. Well, go on. What conditions are necessary and sufficient?

Comment: Your idea is right, it means that is necessary to have $a_{j}\ge 0$ for some $1\le j\le n$.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I misunderstood what the question was asking

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to find necessary and sufficient conditions under which $\|\cdot\|_a$ is a norm. As you have stated, it is necessary that all the $a_j$ are nonnegative.

Comment: Thank you! I was misunderstanding what the question was asking, sorry

Comment: Please in the definition of a norm $N$: is it possible that $N(x)$ may be $+\infty$ or must be strictly positive for every $x$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Student Norms only attain finite values.

Comment: @Dominik Thank you very much. What about seminorms?

Comment: @Dominik I think also seminorms only attain finite values. Do you agree with me? Thanks

Comment: @Student That is correct.